# Dreamweaver shows a strange syntax error in JS File

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, dreamweaver

Dreamweaver shows an error in the file

jquery.jig.js

the file is this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contactform').submit(function(){
    var action = $(this).attr('action');
    $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled').after('<img src="contact-form/assets/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />');
    $("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
    $('#message').hide();      
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "yourPhpFileURL.php",   //put the url of your php file here
        data: $('#contactform').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
            $('#message').slideDown('slow');
            $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('fast',function(){$(this).remove()});
            $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
            if(data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');

            if(data.match('success') != null) $("html,body").animate({
                scrollTop: $("#message").offset().top
                }, 1000, function(){

                });
            if(data.match('success') == null) $("html,body").animate({
                scrollTop: $("#message").offset().top
                }, 1000, function(){
                    //scroll complete function
                });                     
        }
        });

    });

    return false;

});

});
```

The error is showed in the last line, but I cannot understand the reason.

Comment: file looks fine. But i believe Dreamweaver might not like how you write your `if`'s

Comment: What does the error say? Just a line number?

Comment: can't see any major issues myself, couple of minor points $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('fast',function(){$(this).remove()}); 
 needs a semicolon after the .remove(), and I would (even though it shouldn't be any issue) rewrite the if statements with curly braces, and it doesn't seem to make sense to test twice for data.match('success') != null and then test for the oposite. Surely one if else statement should suffice. May help isolate the issue

Comment: the error is simply "syntax error on the line 40" (last line)... I cannot understand the reason... I get the same error also if I remove all the "If"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code through [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)'s JSLint syntax analyzer, and fixed a few errors and etc.  So far, the below validates fine.  Please check it on your end:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contactform').submit(function() {
        var action = $(this).attr('action');
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled').after('<img src="contact-form/assets/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />');
        $("#message").slideUp(750, function() {
            $('#message').hide();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "yourPhpFileURL.php",
                //put the url of your php file here
                data: $('#contactform').serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
                    $('#message').slideDown('slow');
                    $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                    $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                    if (data.match('success') !== null) {
                        $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');
                    }
                    var msg_offset = $("#message").offset().top;
                    if (data.match('success') !== null) {
                        $("html,body").animate({
                            scrollTop: msg_offset
                        }, 1000, function() {

                        });
                    }
                    if (data.match('success') === null) {
                        $("html,body").animate({
                            scrollTop: msg_offset
                        }, 1000, function() {
                            //scroll complete function
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

        });

        return false;

    });

});
```